# i am getting error while installing firebase tools through cmd npm

Tags: npm, firebase-tools

This is the error logs i am get in the commmand line

```
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! syscall open
   npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp/package.json
   npm ERR! errno -4058
   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\package.json'
   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
   npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-02T12_08_50_817Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\hp>cd desktop/

C:\Users\hp\Desktop>cd myprojects/trip

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
description: npm WARN init canceled

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm install -g firebase-toold
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:83b3:80e2:e4a5:58c:6810:23:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-02T12_12_41_688Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

up to date in 512ms

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm help config

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>npm install -g npm@latest
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:91b3:80e2:e4a5:0:6810:23:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-02T12_19_16_661Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\myprojects\trip>
```

does any one knows what i have to  do?
i have to install the firebase-tools package for my flutter project but due to this it does not working. does i have to use the standalone library?
but i dont know how to use it . please help me